# Linux "top" utility on ARM reports numbers that we have verified to be wrong. Why?

Tags: linux, performance, arm

We have an ARM9-based embedded board which is running Linux 2.6.32.20.  The device is a video camera whose associated capture/compression hardware places data into an input fifo in the ARM memory which the ARM then accesses from user space.  We also have a driver for this encoder for high level control.

A thread in the application level code checks this user space fifo and when there is data it sends this out over a socket.  To avoid the overhead of this thread needing to poll the user space fifo for data we have a very simple read() call to the driver which in reality simply pends until there is any data in the fifo (nothing is really "read" into the buffer supplied in the read() call).  This read() call then returns and the thread proceeds to read data from the fifo until it's empty and then pends again by calling the fake read() call.

This system is quite efficient as measured by how many network streams can be transmitted before frame drops are detected.  But we have determined that using the fake read() call causes the Linux "top" utility to report large CPU usage by our app.

We have built 2 versions of the app- one which operates as above and the other which is identical except that it never calls the fake read() but instead polls the fifo with intervening usleep() calls.  When we look at the CPU usage as reported by "top" for the 2 cases when each is sending 5 streams we get:

1) read()   version: CPU 12%
2) usleep() version: CPU 4%

Of course polling in reality is less efficient and if we ignore what "top" is saying and instead just measure how many simultaneous network streams the 2 versions can transmit before we see frame drops then version 1 above wins.

We have verified that the read() call above is operating correctly.  If some bug results in the read() call returning immediately even when there is no data in the fifo then the thread would end up doing expensive continuous polling.  But this is not the case; the read() call causes the thread to run exactly 30 times per second as it should.

We thought that there might be some shortcut taken by our toy busybox version of "top"- but no these results are in the raw numbers in /proc//stat that top uses to calculate its displayed numbers.

This issue must be some limitation of how the Linux kernel itself collects the numbers shown in /proc//stat.

If anyone understands why this should be so please point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: What else is the thread spending CPU time on besides *read()*? If it's doing practically nothing, then it's possible 12% of that nothing could be going in and out of *read()*.

Comment: can you add the /proc/loadavg as well for both cases. I'm pretty sure it is your read that's problematic. Or you are using something like cpufreq's ondemand governor with io_is_busy which alters calculations.

Comment: Does your `top` have **sys** numbers? It is possible that the driver is not yielding during the `read()`. Can you show the driver code? You can easily verify the `/proc/stat` number by running a benchmark program at the same time. If top is lying, the benchmark will go up.  The benchmark can be as simple as a counting loop that prints the count and start/end clock times (assuming you have a functional RTC).  Otherwise, you can use a signal and a stop watch.

Answer (score 1):

I can GUARANTEE that top is not lying to you. If it says your process is using 12% of the CPU, it's using 12% of the CPU. There are no two ways about that.

Obviously, calling usleep will not take much time, because it cause the process to go to sleep for (at least) the amount of time requested. That's probably 100 cycles per call to sleep. Read does much more than that, so I'm not surprised that it takes more CPU time to do that - especially if you do it a lot.

Read will:

1. Check that your handle is valid.
2. Check that your buffer pointer and length are valid.
3. Copy the length from user-space to kernel space.
4. Insert the read data into suitable data structures.
5. Look up the relevant handles and what driver to issue the request to.
6. Issue the read request to your driver.
7. Driver sleeps the process [presuming there is no data available].
8. Driver wakes up the process [when there is data available].
9. Copy the read length data to user-space.
10. Return to caller.

Compare that with usleep:

1. Go to sleep.
2. Wake up.
3. Return to user.

Of coruse "go to sleep" is not a single trivial function, and wake up is not trivial either. But they are the same operations, and during the sleep, the process uses no CPU.

You could easily figure out how much overhead there is in a read by reading from /dev/zero and sleep in between. `/dev/zero` is a device that returns immediately with a buffer filled with zeros.

Alternatively, you could try using something like `oprofile` to do a performance analysis and see where the time is spent.

But I'm pretty sure that your `top` isn't lying.

Comment: How you can GUARANTEE? also what do you consider as using CPU?

Comment: Ok, unless you have hacked the kernel, I can guarantee it! But then if you have hacked the kernel, all bets are off, and you shouldn't be asking here for advice [although I expect that you wouldn't admit that]. 

Using CPU is "any instructions executed during your process being current". When the system is in another process, it accountes for it in that process, and of course, the "idle" process is running if nothing else is ready to run. 

If your video processing is sharing memory with the CPU itself, it will also affect the efficiency of the system, and thus increase the time of a read.

Comment: Don't know why it was down votes, but **gaurentee** is a strong word.  Crazy hardware, weird kernel `.config`, b0Rken `top`, ancient 2.6.32 bug, etc.  I am with you that `top` is  *likely* correct, but **gaurentee**?  Later you say *pretty sure*.  I think you just need an edit; the OP seems to be slamming Linux, if you don't read carefully.  Don't get mad ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, "guarantee" is too strong of a word to use here. I am currently performance testing 2 different ARM based boards, using 3.8 and 3.7 kernels and BOTH are reporting strange things in top. One is using the stock kernel the company shipped, and Arch-Linux on the other. I do not believe these kernels were "hacked" in any way. The hardware just doesn't seem to be playing nice. One is reporting 0% CPU usage for every process, even though the total at the top shows 50% idle. The other is showing a dma driver related process always using 100% of the CPU. So in my very limited experience, top has been the problem I think.